# Trigger Airflow DAG on specific times daily

Tags: python, airflow

How should I pass the `schedule_interval` parameter in order to trigger my DAG `everyday` in specific times, such as at `10:30`, `13:00` and `14:00`?

Comment: see timetables trigger:  https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/authoring-and-scheduling/timetable.html#crondataintervaltimetable

Answer (score 0):

You can pass cron expression to that parameter.
In your case, if you want to schedule the DAG to run `everyday` in specific times, e.g.:

1. `10:30`. You can pass `30 10 * * *`.
2. `13:00`. You can pass `0 13 * * *`.
3. `14:00`. You can pass `0 14 * * *`.

Read more about cron expression [here](https://streamsets.com/blog/cron-expressions/). If you want to test your cron expression, you can use [crontab guru](https://crontab.guru/).

Comment: But I want the DAG to run in all those specific times. Can I pass a list of cron expressions?

Comment: AFAIK, you can't do it. But if you want to run daily in `10:00`, `13:00`, and `14:00` here is the cron expression `0 10,13,14 * * *`. Please notice that I change `10:30` to `10:00`.

Comment: It will trigger the dag `daily at minute 0 past hour 10, 13, and 14`.